# How to make mouse scroll work in AWS Workspace

Tags: amazon-web-services, scroll, vertical-scrolling, amazon-workspaces

I am using AWS Workspace with Linux for some work. And using Windows Client to connect to it.
Everything seems to be working fine except I cannot use mouse scroll in the workspace(not working in firefox/terminal/any-window). (scroll is working fine on the machine where the client is running)

Left-click and right-click both are working fine.

I tried to find it on AWS forums and SO too, but couldn't find anything related to this.  If you try to search the same on Google, there is one similar [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=151445) - but it's related to mouse with some extra buttons.

Scrolling seems to be a basic functionality that should be provided. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Found a solution yet?

Comment: @udondan Its an issue with my laptop/os. When connected using some other laptop, mouse is working in the workspace. Suggest you to check from another laptop to confirm.

Comment: Hm. Thanks. Well, even if it worked on another laptop, my company won't give me a new one, just because scrolling is not working is some effed up application :D

Comment: I can not scroll too. Did you found any solution? Windows is fine but cant scroll in Linux

Comment: On Linux you can hold down the Shift key to scroll horizontally. Absolutely terrible but the only thing I was able to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

Under mouse settings in Windows 10, there's an option there called "scroll inactive windows when I hover over them".  Make sure that is enabled to allow mouse scroll inside virtual desktop.